# I have a .NET console application that runs code in another assembly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a .NET console application (let's call it `Bar.exe`) that runs code in another assembly, let's call it `Foo.dll`. `Foo.dll` references some external assemblies.

Currently I have to reference the external assemblies in both `Foo.dll`'s project and `Bar.exe`'s project. I would like to only reference them in `Foo.dll`'s project as there are many other projects in the solution that reference other external assemblies. The way I have things organized will lead to a cluttered and duplicated situation.

Is there a better way to organize my solution so I don't need to include the external DLLs with `Bar.exe`?

Comment: It isn't clear why you have to reference them.  The build system normally knows how to copy those assemblies into the Bar build directory without your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any code in `Bar.exe` that depends directly on the external assemblies? What build error message do you get when you try to reference only `Foo.dll` from `Bar.exe`?